# How to force upgrading module in odoo

Tags: odoo-8

Please, i have tried to upgrade my module to make the xml changements functional. But, i have recognized that none changement has been done.
I think that the action of upgrading is not working.
Please who can hepl me

Comment: How are you running the server?? Are you using a service? If you are using a service you should stop it first and be sure you stopped it, sometimes it doesn't stop

Comment: And remember that you should use the command line with the argument `--update`

Comment: Check also that you have added your xml file to the data list in the `__openerp__.py` file of your custom module.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your server and upgrade your module then it will work.